# Change Stylesheet and save it to "Cookies / Local storage"

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, stylesheet

I have two **stylesheets**

```
<link href="design/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default">
<link href="design/new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="new">
```

*and I have buttons what change these stylesheets:*

```
<button class="" onclick="swapStyleSheet('design/default.css')">Default</button>
<button class="" onclick="swapStyleSheet('design/new.css')">New</button>
```

*and of course javascript that swap these stylesheets.*

```
    function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
       document.getElementById('design').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

**The question is:**

How to save stylesheets what user clicked on? using **Cookies / Local storage**.

*Even when user leave my page and come back after 4 days.*

> Is better to use **"Cookies"** or **"Local storage"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `load` event of `window` define a variable to store reference to `Blob URL`. If `localStorage` has key, for example, `"styles"`, get `css` from `localStorage`, create a `Blob` with `localStorage.getItem("styles")` set as element of iterable at first parameter, `type` set to `"text/css"`. Pass `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()` to set at value of `#design` `.href`. Else, filter `document.styleSheets` for `.href` which matches `sheet` parameter at `swapStyleSheet` call, create get `.cssText` from `.rules` property lookup, set as `Blob`, perform above described procedures.

```
window.onload = function() {
  let blob, url;

  function setStyle() {
    var sheet = localStorage.getItem("styles");
    blob = new Blob([localStorage.getItem("styles")], {type:"text/css"});    
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.getElementById("design").setAttribute("href", url);
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("style") != null) setStyle();

  function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {

    var rules = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.styleSheets, function(styles) {
      return styles.href.indexOf(sheet) !== -1
    })[0].rules;

    for (var i = 0, css = ""; i < rules.length; i++)  css += rules[i].cssText;

    if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    localStorage.setItem("styles", css);

    setStyle();

  }
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand. **You of course explain it brilliantly**. I just wanted to save stylesheet if I click on button "new" to change the style and keep it even when i reload the page. I don't understand cookies and localstorage.

Comment: Have you read the specification [Web storage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html)?

Comment: I'll read it right now. English is very hard for me but I'll see what I can do

Comment: No worries. Take your time.

Comment: Well I did not get too much information. Can you help me with coding? Please. Its really hard to understand as 13 years old guy.

Comment: Which portion of `javascript` at Answer do you not understand?

Comment: How to store my stylesheet and get it.

Comment: That is what `javascript` at Answer achieves. The text of the `styleSheet` itself is stored in `localStorage`. Are you trying to store only value of `.href` of `<link>` element?

Comment: I am trying to store the stylesheet. _when user come to my website and click in what style he want my website and everytime he visit my website it will show up my webpage in that style he picked._

Comment: That is what `javascript` at Answer achieves. Does approach not return expected result?

Comment: Well as a beginner I don't understand :D I am sorry

Comment: If `localStorage` is set having property `"styles"`, set last `<link>` element which is child node of `<head>` element, `.href` to `Blob URL` of  `localStorage.getItem("styles")`, else iterate `document.styleSheets` to match `.styleSheet` which has `.href` set to parameter passed to `swapStyleSheet`, iterate and concatenate `.rules` of matched `.styleSheet` as a single string,  revoke existing `Blob URL` if defined, set `localStorage` to string; set last `<link>` in `document`, having `.id` set to `"design"` to `Blob URL` of item retrieved from `localStorage.getItem("styles")`.

Answer (score 0):

loalStorage will last until the cache of the client it's cleaned you can set or get that value very easily.

```
 // Store
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
 // Retrieve
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Code from [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Please.  I am in the end

Comment: Add it to the click button event: `function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
       document.getElementById('design').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}` and in the beginning of your script set this href

Comment: So you mean `function swapStyleSheet(sheet){ document.getElementById('design').setAttribute('href', sheet); // Store
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
 // Retrieve
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname"); }`

Comment: Nope, `document.getElementById('design').setAttribute('href', sheet); // will set the href to your tag` `localStorage.setItem("sheet", sheet); // will store the value of the current sheet in local storage` and apart from that at the beginning of your script `document.getElementById('design').setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem("sheet"));` // Will retrieve and set the current value stored in the localstorage